# Replaced third party code with git submodules, now I can't switch branches

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-merge

Here's the story:
I have 2 git branches `master` and `develop`
I'm currently on `develop`.

I've long since had the source files of a third party library included in my repo in the directory `Vendor/MGTwitterEngine`. This code was already merged into master.

Now, on branch `develop`, I've removed the library and replaced it with a git submodule and committed.

The problem is I can no longer switch back to the `master` branch. If I try, I get the following error:

```
The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    Vendor/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterHTTPURLConnection.h
    Vendor/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterHTTPURLConnection.m
    Vendor/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterLibXMLParser.h
    Vendor/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterLibXMLParser.m
    Vendor/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser.h
    Vendor/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser.m
    Vendor/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterMessagesParser.h
    Vendor/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterMessagesParser.m
    ...
   Aborting
```

git thinks the submodule files are "untracked" and won't replace them with the tracked, non-submodule files in the same location.

How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think this is just one of the drawbacks of using submodules.  These problems are described in a section called ["Issues with Submodules" in Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Submodules#Issues-with-Submodules), but in short, the simplest workaround is to move the submodule directory out of the way before switching to the `master` branch:

```
mv Vendor Vendor.moved
git checkout master
```

Similarly, when you change to `develop`, you should do:

```
git checkout develop
mv Vendor.moved Vendor
```

Comment: Of course, as soon as you get past the transition, this issue does disappear. (And to be fair, it is at least somewhat difficult for Git to *safely* switch branches. Unfortunate, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Now it can be made easier. Use command `git checkout -f master`.